# execute more than one js answer in agile toolkit

Tags: atk4

how can I execute more than one js?

```
if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $hashed_user->js()->val("r")->execute();
    $hashed_pass->js()->val("r")->execute();
}
```

the second one doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's rather simple - just put these chains in js() methods second parameter as array.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted) {
    $this->js(null, array(
        $this->js()->doSomething('A'),
        $this->js()->doSomething('B'),
        $this->js()->doSomething('C'),
    ))->execute();

    // this line will be never run
}
```

->execute() should be only one, because it stops rendering of your PHP script and echo out JS response to browser.

Comment: If this answer helped you, then please don't hesitate to accept it as correct and useful :)

Comment: oh yes! thank u very much. Hey DarkSide, You are the best. I have learnt from u many times.